# Error: bad escape in Python script with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a search between lists and return the value when it matches, and when it does not.

```
import re

array = ['brasil','argentina','chile','canada']
array2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo','chile','argentina']

for x,y in zip(array,array2):
  if re.search('\\{}\\b'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("Match: {}".format(x))
  else:
    print("Not match: {}".format(y))
```

Output:

```
Not match: brasil.sao_paulo
Not match: chile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    if re.search('\\{}\\b'.format(x), y, re.IGNORECASE):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
re.error: bad escape \c at position 0
```

Desired output:

```
Match: brasil
Match: argentina
Match: chile
Not match: canada
```

Comment: The regex which fails is `\chile\b`. I imagine that is not what you wanted to search for.

Comment: I would like it to look up regardless of array order

Comment: Example: Array 1 -> Line1 == Array2 -> All lines

Comment: What is the purpose of the initial `\\\` ?

Comment: I'm new to regex, just trying to do it, suggest otherwise?

Comment: First off, you should use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to insert code into your regex. Second off, the first backslash is not needed (and causes your issue), third, use `r''`: `re.escape(x) + r'\b'`

Comment: As others told already, the `\ ` in the beginning causes the problems but for anyone who wonders for this case, why it only complains about `\c` and not about `\b` or `\a`, the reason simply is, these two characters are permitted escape sequences. `\b` means word boundary and `\a` stands for the bell tone character (I memorize the shortcut as 'a' for "alert"), which is implemented to play an OS-specific audio signal or show a visual behaviour. Note, some regex flavors have a meaning for `\c` as ASCII control character. However, it must be followed by a letter, e.g. `\ca` (or otherwise `\cA`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need regex here.

```
group_1 = ['brasil','argentina','chile','canada']
group_2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo','chile','argentina']

for x in group_1:
    # For group 2 only, this picks out the part of the string that appears before the first ".".
  if x in [y.split('.')[0] for y in group_2]:
    print("Match: {}".format(x))
  else:
    print("Not match: {}".format(x))
```

which returns

```
Match: brasil
Match: argentina
Match: chile
Not match: canada
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `zip`, you'll only get pairwise matches. Given the nature of your search, you can just join up the haystack into a space-delimited string and join needles into a pattern with alternation and let `findall` chug away:

```
>>> import re
>>> needles = ['brasil', 'argentina', 'chile', 'canada']
>>> haystack = ['brasil.sao_paulo', 'chile', 'argentina']
>>> re.findall(r"\b%s\b" % "|".join(needles), " ".join(haystack), re.I)
['brasil', 'chile', 'argentina']
```

The intent behind `\\` in the original regex is unclear, so I assume you want `\b` on both sides of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with the `any` method:

```
array = ['brasil', 'argentina', 'chile', 'canada']
array2 = ['brasil.sao_paulo', 'chile', 'argentina']

for x in array:
    if any(x.casefold() in y.casefold() for y in array2):
        print("Match:", x)
    else:
        print("Not match:", x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBCsIwEAXQfU4xdJMGShd1V/AIegEpMrapDcRJSCI0p48mgq04q/nMf2NjWAwdUkLnMMIRLvzm0CvNG@Do7pKCIsxhXJSWZUHCCfnACul2pvVorhaf2vyA7c3A2GwcrKAIiu4ZvEfNgBTrtR3Ry9noqRa5Efc5u/h1nfjIPNYpCnV1wjAufdXAKspJai//SmcT4LEVU3oB)

**Edit**: Using `casefold()` to make it case-insensitive.